# Ruby sprintf, about the "2" in "%02x"

Tags: ruby

```ruby
sprintf("%02x", c)
```

I know this code converts decimal to hex but what does the "2" mean?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25 and http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `0` is the padding character, while `2` is a width specifier that specifies how many characters you want printed. It is intended as the minimum number of characters, so having `02` will always at least print 2 characters and they'll be zero if there's no other data to be shown.